# Ansible Jinja2 get element from list inside dictionary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm unable to get the nth element(IP address) from a list inside a dictionary in Jinja 2.

*my playbook*

```
---
- name: Test dictionaries playbook
  hosts: test
  remote_user: user

  vars:
    list_dict:
      - {"hostname": "server01", "ip": [ '10.10.10.161', '10.10.10.250', '10.228.115.120', '10.10.10.224' ] }
      - {"hostname": "server02", "ip": [ '10.10.10.162', '10.10.10.253', '10.228.115.121', '10.10.10.225' ] }

  tasks:
    - name: Get Facts
      template:
       src: ../template.j2
       dest: /tmp/template-out
      delegate_to: localhost
      with_items: list_dict
```

*the template used 'template.j2'*

```
{% for host in list_dict %}
   Current host is {{host.hostname}}
   The ips for this host are:
   {% for ip in host.ip %}
     {{ ip[0] }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

*Current Output (I guess it's getting the first element of each IP which is '1'*

```
Current host is server01
The ips for this host are:
     1
     1
     1
     1

Current host is server02
The ips for this host are:
     1
     1
     1
     1
```

*Desired Output ( I'd like to get the whole first IP for each host)*

**Any idea how I could acomplish that?**

```
The ips for this host are:
     10.10.10.161


Current host is server02
The ips for this host are:
    10.10.10.162
```

In Python, it'd be something like that:

```
hostname = { "name" : "server02", "ip": [ '10.10.10.162', '10.228.115.121', '10.10.10.225', '10.10.10.251' ]  }

print hostname["ip"][0]
10.10.10.162
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In exactly the same way as you already mentioned. No internal loop is required.

```
{% for host in list_dict %}
   Current host is {{host.hostname}}
   The ips for this host are:
   {{ host.ip[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```